# How do I install the WebP plugin into Photoshop Creative Cloud?

Tags: image, image-processing, webp

I want to use WebP--https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/?csw=1
I think it comes as a plugin from Telegraphics
http://telegraphics.com.au/sw/product/WebPFormat
but I'm not sure how to install it into Adobe Photoshop CC.  I also am running a Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 9):

This question probably belongs to the graphic design stack exchange (https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/), not here. Anyway, you have to copy the plug-in file inside the plug-in directory you can find in C:/Program Files/Adobe/Photoshop CC/Plug-ins, restart Photoshop and you should be able to open webp files.

Note that you have to check what version of Photoshop you are using (32-bit or 64-bit) and use the correct version of the plug-in for each case.

It is possible that you have both versions installed in your computer so you should better copy each version of the plug-in inside the corresponding photoshop plug-in folder.

Comment: In CC 2017 - install in the File Formats folder:
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CC 2017\Required\Plug-Ins\File Formats

Comment: For Mac CC2018 - paste the plugin file in folder: /Applications/Adobe Photoshop CC 2018/Adobe Photoshop CC 2018.app/Contents/Required/Plug-ins/File Formats

Answer (score 0):

In my case I copied from http://telegraphics.com.au/sw/browse/File-Formats webp format 32bits into a Plugins/Extensions folder on PS CS3 and it worked fine. Remember to restart your PS after have copied.